# TypeError: setcoords() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coords1'

Tags: python, pygame

[full code with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9j21.png)

I'm trying to do a class for drawing a triangle but apparently in line 29 there is a problem that i cant solve. I read some other question on here but they've been mainly about 'self' which is not my error

```
 def setcoords(self,coords1):
    self.coords=coords1


triangle.setcoords(((100,100),(150,200),(200,100)))
print (triangle.givecoords())
triangle.setcolor((0,255,0))
triangle.setvisible(True)
triangle.draw()
```

Comment: What is `triangle`? Is it a class? It needs to be an object! See [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects):

```py
my_triangle = triangle()
my_triangle.setcoords(((100,100),(150,200),(200,100)))
```

[Class Names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention and have a [constructor (`__init__`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

```py
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, coords1):
        self.coords = coords1
    # [...] 
 
my_triangle = Triangle([(100,100),(150,200),(200,100)])
```